# How to set the value and mask for non-aligned field

Tags: acl, dpdk

I am trying to set an ACL structure for ICMP packets.
To do so, I set the data pointer to point on the IP src field in the mbuf and use the following structure to define the ACL array:

```
struct icmp_acl_tuple {
uint32_t src_ip;
uint32_t dst_ip;
uint8_t  type;
uint8_t  code;};



static struct rte_acl_field_def icmp_defs[C_NUM_FIELDS_ICMP] = {
{
    .type = RTE_ACL_FIELD_TYPE_BITMASK,
    .size = sizeof(uint8_t),
    .field_index = C_TYPE_FIELD_ICMP,
    .input_index = 0,
    .offset = offsetof (struct icmp_acl_tuple, type),
},
/* next input field (IPv4 source address) - 4 consecutive bytes. */
{
    .type = RTE_ACL_FIELD_TYPE_MASK,
    .size = sizeof (uint32_t),
    .field_index = C_SRC_FIELD_ICMP,
    .input_index = 1,
    .offset = offsetof (struct icmp_acl_tuple, src_ip),
},
/* next input field (IPv4 destination address) - 4 consecutive bytes. */
{
    .type = RTE_ACL_FIELD_TYPE_MASK,
    .size = sizeof (uint32_t),
    .field_index = C_DST_FIELD_ICMP,
    .input_index = 2,
    .offset = offsetof (struct icmp_acl_tuple, dst_ip),
},
/*due to DPDK restrictions, 32bit should be used (although one byte field)*/
{
    .type = RTE_ACL_FIELD_TYPE_BITMASK,
    .size = sizeof (uint32_t),
    .field_index = C_CODE_FIELD_ICMP,
    .input_index = 3,
    .offset = offsetof (struct icmp_acl_tuple, code),
},};
```

My issue is with the 'Code' field (the last one).
I am unable to get the desired action.

How should I set the value and mask for this field?
I tried both with u8, u32, u32 with offset. nothing worked.

Comment: "I tried both with u8, u32, u32 with offset. nothing worked" -- better show us the code or a minimal working example. The fields in the input tuple must be in network byte order, while ACL rules must be in host byte order. I guess that might be the issue, but without a code it is just a guess...

Answer (score 0):

The size field of the last parameter `C_CODE_FIELD_ICMP` should be set to `1` instead of `4`. because as per DPDK-ACL `size The size parameter defines the length of the field in bytes.`. The issue is not with `RTE_ACL_FIELD_TYPE_BITMASK`.